# How to include text inside div using HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpcontext, htmlgenericcontrol

I have included a div in my web page using HtmlGenericControl.
With a button click , i want to add text inside the div using HttpContext. I don't want to use InnerHtml because the browser hangs when the text i want to include is very long.
I tried the following way but it prints the text outside the div.
Please Help.
Thanks!

```
 public partial class TextViewer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public HttpContext ctx;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        myDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Blue");
        this.Controls.Add(myDiv);
        ctx = this.Context;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ctx.Response.Write("supposed to be printed inside myDiv.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to the `HttpContext` from code behind and access its value from jQuery.

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    myDiv.ID = "myDiv";
    myDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Blue");
    this.Controls.Add(myDiv);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Application["MyData"] = "Supposed to be printed inside myDiv.";
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var data = '<%= HttpContext.Current.Application["MyData"] != null ? HttpContext.Current.Application["MyData"].ToString() : "" %>';
            $("#myDiv").append(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful. Is there a way to do it without using javascript?

Comment: Now i have created a method instead of button click that is called everytime for a new line read from a text file. but nothing is printed. while running  with debugger it shows that jquery funtion is accessed only once. is there a way?

Comment: You can't do that.That's not the way web works.You construct the page on the server and send it to the client.You need to read the whole content of the text file into a variable and set it once

Answer (score 0):

In such case, you can split your text into many spans and set each span's text separately

```
foreach(var paragraph in myText)
 {
    var span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    span.InnerHtml = paragraph; 
    myDiv.Controls.Add(span);
 }
```